# Is it possible to make an Attrs class comparable based on computed properties?

Tags: python-3.x, python-attrs

I'm implementing a simple load balancer for my project with Python3.7.

I use a `queue.PriorityQueue` to hold a set of predefined workers. Workers' order in the queue are defined by each of their loading which is evaluated based on the number of jobs a worker is assigned. That is, there is a `jobs` property which is a list of Job instances, and the loading is a computed by the length of `jobs`.

Each iteration of job assignment, a worker with the lowest loading (the least number of jobs) is retrieved via `queue.get()` and after assignment, it will be `put` back to the queue.

Here is the simplified snippet.

```py
import attr
from typing import List

from .job import Job

@attr.s(order=True)
class Worker:
    jobs: List[Job] = attr.ib(factory=list, order=False)

    @property
    def loading(self):  # how to make Worker comparable according to this property?
        return len(self.jobs)
```

I know I can achieve this if I add those dunder methods for comparison myself, i.e. `__ne__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__` and `__ge__`.

But my question is, is it possible to make an `attrs` class comparable based on computed properties?
And if it's possible, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`attrs` currently has no direct support for properties unfortunately.  I think your best bet is leaving `order=False` and use `functools.total_ordering`.